# ¿Cómo hago una impresión en una ventana aparte del cmd?

Tags: python, tkinter, print

Bueno primero que nada estoy usando python 3.10 bueno como vieron en el titulo quiero cambiar el sistema imprimir y crear uno yo mismo y que aparezca en una ventana aparte para que tengan una idea aqui les dejo mi prototipo:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk


class StdOutRedirect:
    def __init__(self,  text: tk.Text) -> None:
     self._text = text

    def write(self,  out: str) -> None:
     self._text.insert(tk.END,  out)


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.stdout_text = tk.Text(
         self,  bg="black",  fg="#38B179",  font=("Helvetica", 15))
        self.stdout_text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        sys.stdout = StdOutRedirect(self.stdout_text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    print("Hola mundo")
    print("Hola Juan")
    print("StackOverflow")

    root.mainloop()
```

Y este es el resultado:

[image: resultado]

solo me falta poner la funcion principal en un def print(text) pero me he trabado ahi me podrias dar una mano por favor

Comment: No veo la pregunta. Dices que quieres hacer una cosa, y luego muestras código de cómo lo harías, y el código funciona y hace lo que quieres. ¿No? ¿Entonces?

Comment: Quieres cambiar cuál sistema? Se entiende el prototipo, pero no se entiende qué quieres que salga allá. Gracias por traducir la pregunta.

Comment: @abulafia bueno como dije quiero cambiar el print del sistema asi que quisiera saber como poner en def print(text):
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    print("Hola mundo")
    print("Hola Juan")
    print("StackOverflow")

    root.mainloop()

Comment: @Alfabravo quiero que salga todos los print que haga haciendo un def print(text) pero ahi me traba y nose como continuar

Comment: no entiendo bien la pregunta. quizas el problema es que el text escribe (inserta texto )en una posición decimal renglon.carcter en tcl para encribir en el ultimo renglon siempre ponemos como posición "end.end" la primera linea del text es 0.0 renglon 0 caracter 0 lo que quieres es un def que escriba donde?? al principio o al final??

Answer (score 1):

pues la respuesta es mas facil de lo que crei perdon por ser tonto para los que no se dieron cuenta empezaria asi:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk


class StdOutRedirect:
    def __init__(self,  text: tk.Text) -> None:
     self._text = text

    def write(self,  out: str) -> None:
     self._text.insert(tk.END,  out)


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.stdout_text = tk.Text(
         self,  bg="black",  fg="#38B179",  font=("Helvetica", 15))
        self.stdout_text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        sys.stdout = StdOutRedirect(self.stdout_text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

y aqui hirian todos los prints que quieras y cuando hayas coloquado tus print pones:

```
root.mainloop()
```